# Convert JSON object and array to same class in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to convert a JSON returned from a third party API, into VB.NET class object. The problem is that the JSON sometimes returns a node as an Array of objects and sometimes the same node as an single Object. So, while trying to convert when it receives Array of objects, the code throws exception.

```
    {
  "correlation_id": "228.9219622269229",
  "Error": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "code": "401",
        "description": "Unauthorized"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transaction_status": "Not Processed"
}
```

As you can see, there is an array of Error messages under Error->messages node. But sometimes, the JSON returned is simpy and object of Error messages something like

```
{
  "correlation_id": "228.9219622269229",
  "Error": {
    "messages": {
        "code": "401",
        "description": "Unauthorized"
      }
  },
  "transaction_status": "Not Processed"
}
```

I try to deserialize this JSON to the following class

```
Public Class PayeezyRefundResponse
    Public correlation_id As String
    Public transaction_status As String
    Public validation_status As String
    Public transaction_type As String
    Public transaction_id As String
    Public transaction_tag As String
    Public bank_resp_code As String
    Public bank_message As String
    Public [Error] As PayeezyError
End Class
Public Class PayeezyError
    Public messages As PayeezyErrorMessages()
End Class
Public Class PayeezyErrorMessages
    Public code As String
    Public description As String
End Class
```

But when the JSON returns Error message as single object, the code throws exception on PayeezyError class. How can I convert the JSON to this class so that it works in both the cases (i.e. with Array of objects and with single Object) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a custom converter that can handle both cases as a **`List(Of PayeezyErrorMessage)`**.
This converter always returns a `List(Of PayeezyErrorMessage)`, even when the JSON contains a single object.

**Note**: in code, `PayeezyErrorMessages`, plural, has been renamed to `PayeezyErrorMessage`, single, since this class generates a single object.

The custom converter is added to the property as an attribute:

```
<JsonConverter(GetType(PayeezyErrorsConverter(Of PayeezyErrorMessage)))>
Public Messages As List(Of PayeezyErrorMessage)
```

Refactored code:

```
Public Class PayeezyRefundResponse
    ' [...]
    <JsonProperty("Error")>
    Public Errors As PayeezyErrors
End Class

Public Class PayeezyErrors
    <JsonProperty("messages")>
    <JsonConverter(GetType(PayeezyErrorsConverter(Of PayeezyErrorMessage)))>
    Public Messages As List(Of PayeezyErrorMessage)
End Class

Public Class PayeezyErrorMessage
    Public code As String
    Public description As String
End Class
```

Custom converter:
 <sub>►  The writer part is not implemented, since you probably won't need to send back this JSON</sub>

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class PayeezyErrorsConverter(Of T)
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return (objectType = GetType(List(Of T)))
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Dim token As JToken = JToken.Load(reader)
        If token.Type = JTokenType.Array Then
            Return token.ToObject(Of List(Of T))()
        End If
        Return New List(Of T)() From {
            token.ToObject(Of T)()
        }
    End Function

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanWrite() As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```